# How to create a Pandas dataframe for each table meta data (Column Name, Type, Format) stored within a Database Schema in nested JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas, database, nested

I have a JSON file which contains the meta data for tables held within a schema.

I would like to create a dataframe for each table defined within the JSON file i.e. Person, HomeAddress, Employment.  The Person and Employment are at the same level, but HomeAddress in nested within Person.

e.g. dataframe(Person)

```
 Column_Name     Type     Format      Required
 Person_ID       Integer              Yes
 DateOfBirth     String   date-time   Yes
 ...........
```

The contents of the file is as follows;

```json
{
    "$id": "12121212",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "PersonId": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "Person": {
            "type": ["object", "null"],
            "properties": {
                "PersonId": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "DateOfBirth": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "DateOfBirthVerified": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "Sex": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "Surname": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "Initials": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "Forenames": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "Title": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "NationalIdNumber": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "HomeAddress": {
                    "type": ["object", "null"],
                    "properties": {
                        "EffectiveDate": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "date-time"
                        },
                        "EndDate": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "date-time"
                        },
                        "Category": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                        "Line1": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                        "Line2": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                        "Line3": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                        "Line4": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                        "City": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                        "County": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                        "Country": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                        "CareOfAddressee": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                        "PostCode": {
                            "type": ["string", "null"]
                        },
                        "SuspectAddress": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        },
                        "Overseas": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": ["EffectiveDate", "EndDate", "Category", "Line1", "Line2", "Line3", "Line4", "City", "County", "Country", "CareOfAddressee", "PostCode", "SuspectAddress", "Overseas"]
                }
            },
            "required": ["PersonId", "DateOfBirth", "DateOfBirthVerified", "Sex", "Surname", "Initials", "Forenames", "Title", "NationalIdNumber", "HomeAddress"]
        },
        "Employment": {
            "type": ["object", "null"],
            "properties": {
                "EmployeeReference": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                },
                "DateFirstEmployed": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "PayrollNumber": {
                    "type": ["string", "null"]
                }
            },
            "required": ["EmployeeReference", "DateFirstEmployed", "PayrollNumber"]
        }
    },
    "required": ["PersonId", "Person", "Employment"]
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you've tried so far, even if it is not yet working. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Let `d` be the dictionary of the file contents. Then you could address this recursively as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_props(d, required=[]):
    props = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if 'type' in v.keys():
                props.append({
                    'Column_Name': k,
                    'Format': v['format'] if 'format' in v.keys() else np.NaN,
                    'Type': v['type'] if isinstance(v['type'], str) else v['type'][0],
                    'Required': 'Yes' if k in required else 'No'
                })
            props.extend(get_props(v, required=d['required'] if 'required' in d else []))
    return props

df = pd.DataFrame(get_props(d))
print(df)
```

prints

| index | Column_Name | Format | Type | Required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | PersonId | NaN | integer | Yes |
| 1 | Person | NaN | object | Yes |
| 2 | PersonId | NaN | integer | Yes |
| 3 | DateOfBirth | date-time | string | Yes |
| 4 | DateOfBirthVerified | NaN | boolean | Yes |
| 5 | Sex | NaN | string | Yes |
| 6 | Surname | NaN | string | Yes |
| 7 | Initials | NaN | string | Yes |
| 8 | Forenames | NaN | string | Yes |
| 9 | Title | NaN | string | Yes |
| 10 | NationalIdNumber | NaN | string | Yes |
| 11 | HomeAddress | NaN | object | Yes |
| 12 | EffectiveDate | date-time | string | Yes |
| 13 | EndDate | date-time | string | Yes |
| 14 | Category | NaN | string | Yes |
| 15 | Line1 | NaN | string | Yes |
| 16 | Line2 | NaN | string | Yes |
| 17 | Line3 | NaN | string | Yes |
| 18 | Line4 | NaN | string | Yes |
| 19 | City | NaN | string | Yes |
| 20 | County | NaN | string | Yes |
| 21 | Country | NaN | string | Yes |
| 22 | CareOfAddressee | NaN | string | Yes |
| 23 | PostCode | NaN | string | Yes |
| 24 | SuspectAddress | NaN | boolean | Yes |
| 25 | Overseas | NaN | boolean | Yes |
| 26 | Employment | NaN | object | Yes |
| 27 | EmployeeReference | NaN | string | Yes |
| 28 | DateFirstEmployed | date-time | string | Yes |
| 29 | PayrollNumber | NaN | string | Yes |